Integral of a 1-form over a singleton
The integral
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$$
can be seen as the integral of a 1-form ($f(x)\,dx=dF$) over an interval ($[a,b]$). By Stokes' theorem, this integral equals
$$\int_{\{a,b\}}F=F(b)-F(a)$$
which is the fundamental theorem of calculus. Now, when $a=b$, the formula becomes
$$\int_a^adF=\int_{\{a\}}F=F(a),$$
but of course the first expression equals $0$. What is the error with this reasoning?

A singleton is $0$-dimensional, so Stokes' Theorem doesn't apply.

How did the $d$ disappear when you wrote $\int_a^a dF = \int_{{a}} dF = \int_{{a}} F$?

@TedShifrin that's Stokes' theorem

@TedShifrin I'm far from an expert of anything lol, that's why I asked this question.

@TedShifrin I don't think anyone except you is making any claim about how to write Sto'kes theorem, merely about what it says.

Oh, good point. @Elvis: Sorry I misinterpreted your comment as a comment on the punctuation in my answer, instead. I apologize. No, the boundary of ${a}$ is not itself, as boundary always has to lower dimension. The boundary of ${a}$ is usually considered to be the empty set.

@TedShifrin oh okay, I didn't understand the reason for the bitter answer lol. It was just a misunderstanding. And thanks for the answer. I was confused because of the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348448/for-a-finite-set-in-mathbbr-the-interior-is-empty-and-the-closure-and-boun

Ah, different use of the word boundary. Topological boundary is very different from boundary of a manifold with boundary or of a simplex. For example, if you consider a semicircle in the plane, every point is a topological boundary point, but only the endpoints are boundary points in the manifold/simplex setting.

@TedShifrin thanks, I understand now. I don't actually know much about topology or Stokes' theorem, I have a very shallow understanding of it, thus the stupid question. I'm reading Baby Rudin, but I still have to get to the part about differential forms and right now they're just some mysterious thing that I have seen mentioned a lot, but that I don't understand at all.

I don’t recommend Rudin at all for the multivariable material. For some of this stuff, you might check out my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile.

@TedShifrin oh, why? I've always seen Rudin praised a lot.

The book is a classic, renowned for tight, unmotivated exposition with zero pictures/diagrams. But those of us who are geometrically inclined never praise Chapter 9.

@TedShifrin ah, okay, I actually enjoy that style a lot. I started reading Bourbaki's Algebra recently and I really like it.

Stokes's Theorem does apply if you interpret it in the setting of (smooth) singular chains. Take the singular $1$-chain $\sigma$ defined by $\sigma(t)=a$ for $t\in [0,1]$. Then
$$\int_\sigma dF = \int_{\partial\sigma} F = F(\sigma(1))-F(\sigma(0)) = 0,$$
as it should.

In order to use the Stokes' theorem for computing the integral
$$\int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \text{d} x,$$
we have to interpret it as an integral over the $1$-dimensional manifold $[a, b]$ with boundary $\{ a, b \}$.${}^{1}$  This correctly justisfies the result $F(b) - F(a)$.
But when you consider the integral
$$\int \limits_a^a \text{d} F,$$
there is no way to interpret it as an integral over a manifold.${}^2$ $\text{d}F$ is a $1$-form, so the $0$-dimensional manifold $\{ a \}$ does not work - we need a $1$-dimensional manifold here. This is where your argument breaks.
A second problem - not as important as the first one, because it appears when things are already broken - is the mysterious equality
$$\int \limits_a^a \, \text{d} F = \int \limits_{\{a\}} F,$$
where as mentioned in the comments, the $\text{d}F$ magically turned into $F$. Even if we tried to justify it using the Stokes' theorem (forgetting for a moment that the left hand side is meaningless), the $\{ a \}$ would have to arise as the boundary of something - and it is far from obvious what that "something" should be.

${}^1$ Both the interval and its boundary have to be given a proper orientation before the Stokes' theorem can be used, but I assume there are no issues with this part.
${}^2$ It is, however, possible to interpret it as an integral over a $1$-chain, as described in Ted Shifrin's answer.

I thought $\partial{a}={a}$.

As far as I know, the boundary of any $0$-dimensional manifold could be either $\varnothing$ or undefined, but definitely not anything else.

There may be some confusion between the fundamental topological notion of a boundary (closure minus the interior), and the notion of "boundary" used in homology and the study of simplexes and simplicial complexes. They are in fact different notions, but commonly indicated by the same symbol $\partial$. The "simplicial" boundary operator satisfies $\partial^2=0$ ("the boundary of a boundary is empty"). See e.g. here.

Good point. The boundary of a manifold is yet another notion, similar but different from the two.

@printf oooh, yeah, I guess that's where my confusion comes from.

When using differential forms the regions we integrate over are oriented. Also boundaries are oriented.
For example, we can define $[a,b]$ to be positively oriented when $a<b$ and negatively oriented when $b<a.$ Therefore $[a,b]$ and $[b,a]$ have opposite orientation. Let us symbolically write $[a,b]=-[b,a].$
Also the boundaries are oriented. If $[a,b]$ is positively oriented then $\{b\}$ is positively oriented and $\{a\}$ negatively oriented. That's why $\int_{[a,b]} f'(x)\,dx = f(b) - f(a)$ with a positive sign at $b$ and a negative sign at $a.$ Symbolically,
$$
\int_{[a,b]} f'(x) \, dx = \int_{\{b\}-\{a\}} f(x) \, dx.
$$
When $b=a$ we get $\{b\}-\{a\}=0.$ The zero is not the empty set but the zero chain. The integral over the zero chain vanishes.

Do you treat $[a, b]$ as a manifold with boundary anywhere in your answer, or always as a chain?

@Adayah. As a chain. But I haven't really studied chains so I might use incorrect notation. The point of my answer - that things are oriented and have signs, even the end points - should hopefully be clear, though.
